# InvalidArgumentException : View [themes.] not found

Tags: laravel

I get the following error message out of the blue.

> InvalidArgumentException  : View [themes.] not found.
>   Exception trace:
>   1   Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder::findInPaths("themes.")
>           C:\xampp\htdocs\RoosterIKEA\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder.php:92
>   2 Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder::findNamespacedView("mail::themes.")
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\RoosterIKEA\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder.php:76

Any idea which file this could be and what is going on?

Comment: Post your mail views

Answer (score 2):

In the class `Illuminate\Mail\Markdown` line 64

```php
return new HtmlString(($inliner ?: new CssToInlineStyles)->convert(
    $contents, $this->view->make('mail::themes.'.$this->theme)->render()
));
```

It appears that `$this->theme` is an empty string

Now the class already defines the property on line 24

```php
/**
 * The current theme being used when generating emails.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $theme = 'default';
```

Which means that you may have overridden this property by an empty string or maybe a null value in your markdown mailable

If you publish the components by

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

You'll see a CSS file in `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes` named `default.css`

I found a way to reproduce this error on purpose to have a Mailable class like so

Run

```
php artisan make:mail OrderShipped --markdown=emails.orders.shipped
```

Then override the theme property by an empty string

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OrderShipped extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $theme = ''; // <--- HERE

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.orders.shipped');
    }
}
```

Now send an email

```php
use App\User;
use App\Mail\OrderShipped;

Route::get('/', function () {
    \Mail::to(User::first())->send(new OrderShipped());
});
```

And you would get the same error
[image]

The solution here is to either remove the `protected $theme = '';` property or set it to `default`

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did already have that file correctly. What I was doing wrong was that my mail.php file in 'config/mail' had 'markdown' => [
        'theme' => '','